# 'Process finished with exit code 0' with flask in IntelliJ; server doesn't run

Tags: python, flask, intellij-idea, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I'm using the flask web framework, I have made some endpoint for Backend API, but I got some problem. I predicted if I run this code, then the localhost server should run. However, it doesn't work and just appeared that message:

> Process finished with exit code 0

I've tried to solve this problem from the googling, I found some solutions and followed them, but it still doesn't work. The picture I posted is I set now. Please help me. And thank you!

[image: Using IntelliJ, with WebFramework flask]

Comment: Exit code 0 normally means it exited normally.

Comment: I know but I just want message like this:
 * Serving Flask app "test" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: Your code sample would be useful. Are you starting the sever in your code? You should either start it in the code with app.run(), or run it as module with `python -m flask run`. Regardless, I would start by looking at how you start the server. Also, have you tried creating "Flask server" run configuration?

Comment: Yes I have and I already solved it. I just added the codes like this: if __name__ == '__main__': app.run(debug=True, port=5000)

Comment: @ejjang2030 Hi, i appreciate if you remove your latest question on sequence with in Kotlin topic despite that i fully addressed your question, it get lots of bad feedback on community, thanks.